# What is the value of $\int_0^4g'(x)\arctan^2(2g(x)+3)dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> x& \text{0} & \text{1} & \text{2} & \text{3} & \text{4}\\ \hline
> g(x) & 1 & \frac{1}{8} & -\frac{3}{4}& -\frac{13}{8} & -\frac{5}{2}\\ \hline
> \end{array}
>
> Selected values of the twice-differentiable function $g$ are given in the table above. What is the value of
>
> $$\int_0^4g'(x)\arctan^2(2g(x)+3)dx?$$

I have been given this problem from a student preparing for BC calculus.  I tried to use integration by part to change to  the following  expression but  could not find ways to continue. I am not sure if this is the right direction. I'd like to get some hints or suggestions on how to move forward.  Thanks in advance!

$$\begin{align*}
&\int_0^4g'(x)\arctan^2(2g(x)+3)dx\\&=\int_0^4\arctan^2(2g(x)+3)dg(x)\\&=\arctan^2(2g(x)+3)g(x)|_0^4-\int_0^4g(x)d(\arctan^2(2g(x)+3))
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: The change of variables $u=2g(x)+3$ converts it into $-\frac12\int_{-2}^5\arctan^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, but this integral is not elementary, [it seems](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+arctan%5E2%28x%29%2C+x%3D-2..5).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral has to be evaluated as a sum (in absence of analytic expression of $g(x)$) where:

1. The interval is $\delta_i=x_{i+1}-x_i$. In this case $\delta_i=1$.
2. The value of the function is $g_i=g(x_i).$
3. The value of the derivative is $g’_i=\frac{g_{i+1}-g_i}{\delta_i}=g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i).$

Such a possible sum would be $$\sum_{i=0}^3{\arctan^2(2g(x_i)+3)\cdot (g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i))}.$$

There are alternative ways to construct the sum. For example considering $g_i=g(x_{i+1})$. The results will differ since this is an approximate numerical evaluation of the definite integral.

Comment: Thanks! It is about -3.63 and consistent with the answer provided.